# Rails caching as standard practice or based on traffic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

Is caching considered a standard practice or is it only necessary as traffic grows? It is not a retail site, simply information sharing for an organization with likely no more than a few hundred members anytime soon.

Additionally, it would require some memcache plugin on heroku, and while most of them do have a free package, I am not sure when that would be reached.

Comment: Seen my answer? Found it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing to use caching or not belongs to you. If your server specs as tight and you expect sometimes pick of traffic and you need to keep your application highly responsive then caching may help to improve response times.

But it's not mandatory and it ad up code to write, test, and maintain. So if you don't need it it could be a time consuming task. Choice is yours.

As for Heroku I let someone with more knowledge than me answer to you